# how to use anchors on swapping content?

Tags: html, css

I have two wrappers A and B swapping visibility due to @support. If B is supported the divs of B are visible, if B is not supported the divs of A are visible.

I use these wrappers to swap div-contents (same images, but different sizes) and now I am facing the problem with setting anchors to elements inside the wrappers now. The divs in A and divs in B should share the same anchors, but I know that I should not give same id twice to different contents.

What can I do? Is it somehow possible to make elements on both sides share the same anchors? Or is there another way to solve this?

```css
<style type="text/css">
 

.A {display: block}  
.B {display: hidden}

  
@support (...)

{html {...}
  
.A {display: hidden}  
.B {display: block}

 }


</style>
```

```html
<body>


<div class="A">  

<div id="anchor-x">
<...>
</div>

<div id="anchor-y">
<...>
</div>

<div id="anchor-y">
<...>
</div>



<div class="B"> 

<div id="anchor-x">
<...>
</div>

<div id="anchor-y">
<...>
</div>

<div id="anchor-z">
<...>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you not set the Ids on `A` or `B` elements at run time using JavaScript depending on which is visible?

Comment: yeah, thanks for the idea, but I want to do it without java. hope there is some way..

Comment: You realise that Java and JavaScript are entirely different programming languages, right?

Comment: of course I mean script! Sorry, I just wrote too fast ;-) know any other idea?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're trying to select A or B depending on which is visible?

Comment: If B is supported B gets visible, if B is not supported A gets visible. I use these wrappers to swap two different contents (e.g. same images, but different sizes) and what I want is attaching same anchors to these two contents of A and B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to get your ids out of the containers and have sub-containers in each section:

```html
<div id="anchor-x">
  <div class="A X">  
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="B X">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

<div id="anchor-y">
  <div class="A Y">  
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="B Y">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

<div id="anchor-z">
  <div class="A Z">  
  ...
  </div>
  <div class="B Z">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

You might also want to have a look at [srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), which takes the responsiveness problem down to `<img>` element level.

Comment: yes, of course! So logic to just wrap both with an id and let classes do the jobs inside... that works fine for me - anything can be done.... ;- )  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have two classes on your parent element and allow the cascade of CSS to overwrite properites of one class with the properties of another. Both will have equal specificity so CSS will use the last rules defined. This will likely change your overall approach, but it does allow for conditional logic without the use of javascript.

```css
<style type="text/css">
 

.A {display: none}  
.B {display: block}

  
@support (...)

{html {...}
  
.A {display: block}  
.B {display: none}

 }


</style>
```

```html
<body>


<div class="A B">  

<div id="anchor-x">
<...>
</div>

<div id="anchor-y">
<...>
</div>

<div id="anchor-y">
<...>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried out, but it seems, that this leads to splash the rule. A and B is showing together and none of both is hiding anymore. Maybe I have to change the content of A and B somehow or I don't get the whole approach of it right. For now I chose solution above...